# Secure Global Desktop(SGD) certification?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, sgd

I have a problem with updating SGD certificate on my local machine.

I am using a self-signed certificate, and can't get the certificate to change the valid from field (ends in 2022) although the new certificate in the .pem file is valid till 2024.

[Certificate Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Adaj.png)

I want to put a new cert here for SGD.

I have tried everything on the tarantella/sgd website and still no change.

Comment: Many TLS clients will not trust certificates beyond a one year validity period, no matter what the actual period in the certificate is.

Comment: Oke i understand that. But even so when i create the cert the new date should be from now till Nov 2022. I get no changes on webserver after doing certuse but certinfo shows the certificate has changed.